# Facebook: Get all "Likes" for a specific page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently planning a facebook integration on our website. In the example given at the Getting Started page (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph), you can see that I like "The Rock" on Imdb. If I were Imdb, would it be possible to query the user object to get all likes on Imdb? For example would it be possible for them to build a page like "these are the films where you clicked the like button on our website"?

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the likes for a page you need to do this:

use http://graph.facebook.com/

this will return a JSON object be default. Just snatch the `likes` property off it.
http://graph.facebook.com/wearex3 for example

But what you are asking requires you to request access to the user's data and from there get all the likes.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web are what you want to read.